# Bulk publish option (Publish inc. Subnodes) with cache in magnolia

Tags: caching, magnolia

I am using magnolia enterprise standard version 5.3. We have publish and publish inc. sub nodes  option for different apps. Can someone please tell me how cache work when we publish a tree structure? i means to say that, is it publish each node one by one and after publishing each node is it flush the public cache? or first it publish whole tree and then flush public cache?

Actually i want to apply wait time for bulk publish? before that i want to understand cache role while we publish the tree structure.

Can we add wait time for bulk publish?

I am not talking about multisite cache things.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how you configured the cache (or flush policy (or actually the observer that triggers flush policy). IIRC, by default, it is configured such that when event ("something was published") arrives, it will wait and collect all other incoming activations that come within one second. If nothing comes in one second since last event, the event with aggregated messages is passed on to flush policy. If, on the other hand, the events keep arriving, observation will keep collecting and aggregating those events for maximum of 4 seconds before reacting and flushing the cache. (I hope, 1 sec and 4 secs are the correct intervals, but it has been couple of years since I was last time digging anything in that area, so it might have been slightly changed since.)

In EE you have also possibility to configure other caching policies and can have dual cache where one is always pre-heated w/ new content before other is flushed or you can write completely custom policy that suits your needs.